# WWW or no WWW - WHERE DO I CONFIGURE THIS?

Tags: iis, configuration

For my site i need to have www included but currently it's saying Under Construction when i go to the site with www.

For example:

www.example.com - gives me Under Construction

example.com - works fine

Where is this configured is it something in IIS or is it something the my ISP should configure?

Answer (score 2):

If you `nslookup www.example.com` and `nslookup example.com` do they both resolve to the same address? If so then you need to set up the host header for the www one on the server. If not you will need to set up the 'A' record first then sort out the host header if required.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to consider the DNS side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something your ISP should configure in IIS - assuming you use shared hosting you do that yourself somewhere in the control panel.

If you self-host.... go to IIS control panel and look at the site BINDINGS. You miss one for www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

the www is the "subdomain"

your domain name has a configuration which allows you to say the servers which should handle connections to particular domains.

Normally you would configure *.yourdomain.com to point to the server you are hosting on using an "A" record.

Depending on how you have obtained your "website" you may or may not have access to these settings. Commonly the service provider takes care of this and hides it behind their own configuration interface.

You may also be able to use a redirection alias at the domain level to make *.yourdomain.com resolve to yourdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to configure IIS.

**See it on xoc.net: [IIS: Redirect a domain such as xoc.net to www.xoc.net](http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/domain.asp).**

Or see a more general guide at [Microsoft Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)